# Integrate OpenCV webcam into a Kivy user interface

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, kivy

My current program is in Python and uses OpenCV. I rely on webcam captures and I am processing every captured frame:

```
import cv2

# use the webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    # read a frame from the webcam
    ret, img = cap.read()
    # transform image
```

I would like to make a Kivy interface (or another graphical user interface) with buttons, keeping already existing  functionality with webcam captures.

I found this example: 
https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__camera__main__py.html 
 — but it doesn’t explain how to acquire the webcam image to process it with OpenCV.

I found an older example:
http://thezestyblogfarmer.blogspot.it/2013/10/kivy-python-script-for-capturing.html
— it saves screenshots to disk using the ‘screenshot’ function. Then I can read the saved files and process them, but this seems to be an unnecessary step.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found this example here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/N18DmblNWb0

It converts the opencv captures to kivy textures, so you can do every kind of cv transformations before displaying it to your kivy interface.

```
__author__ = 'bunkus'
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture

import cv2

class CamApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.img1=Image()
        layout = BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(self.img1)
        #opencv2 stuffs
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cv2.namedWindow("CV2 Image")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/33.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):
        # display image from cam in opencv window
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        cv2.imshow("CV2 Image", frame)
        # convert it to texture
        buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
        buf = buf1.tostring()
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr') 
        #if working on RASPBERRY PI, use colorfmt='rgba' here instead, but stick with "bgr" in blit_buffer. 
        texture1.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        # display image from the texture
        self.img1.texture = texture1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Using this aproach and hidding cv window makes the app load faster than kivy cam example.

Comment: mixing kivy and `cv.imshow` is a terrible idea. just strip all the `imshow` and `namedWindow` calls. -- the important part of this answer is the "texture" and blitting stuff

Comment: yes, it is a terrible idea. I left those as example. Not necessary in retrospective

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* I have no clue how OpenCV works, but I found [camera_opencv.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py), so this means there is an easy way how to work with it.

As you see in camera example, this is the default way and when you look in `__init__.py` for camera you can see [opencv in providers](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py#L150) so perhaps it works with OpenCV out of the box. Check log if you can see OpenCV detected as a provider. You should see `CameraOpenCV` written somewhere if it's detected and it should show itself when capturing image.

If you however want to work with OpenCV directly(i.e. `cap.read()` and similar stuff), then you need to write your own handler for the provider or append more options to the `camera_opencv` file.