# Integrate a cv2 camera into kv as a Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, opencv

So I want the user to click a button that will move them to the window with a QR scanner, which I found already written code for using cv2. The issue is that it just creates a cv2 frame instead of a kv screen, and the button that is supposed to be on that screen is not there, it just shows the previous screen with a cv2 frame in a different window

Part with the cv2 webcam screen:

```
class QrScan(Screen):
    def runcam(self):
        while True:
            _, frame = cap.read()
            decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(frame)
            for obj in decodedObjects:
                cv2.putText(frame, str(obj.data), (50, 50), font, 2,
                            (255, 0, 0), 3)
            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    def back(self):
        sm.current = "main"
```

The .kv for it:

```
<QrScan>:
    name: "Qr"
    on_pre_enter: root.runcam()
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.1}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**4
            text: "Back"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.back()
```

I have seen integration where the whole app is just a cv2 webcam, but those solutions don't work for screens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrate OpenCV webcam into a Kivy user interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749378/integrate-opencv-webcam-into-a-kivy-user-interface)

Comment: unfortunately that ne doesn't help since there the whole app is a cv2 webcam and it uses a box layout, but I need it on a screen